# Send an intent to another running application

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have a 3rd party app running in the background that my application is trying to interface with but am having a bit of trouble.

To achieve what i want, their API simply tells me to send the intent

```
com.company.name.android.DO_STUFF
```

I have tried to do this in many ways including:

```
 intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
        "com.company.name.android.DO_STUFF");
if (intent == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.app_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
} else {
    intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

but is always unable to start the activity and send the attemp. When it does though (without the null catch), it returns an android.content.ActivityNotFoundException.

Any direction on how to send this intent would be highly appreciated. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the app is expecting a broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.company.name.android.DO_STUFF");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, I have tried this previously and through no errors are produced, it doesn't seem to have any effect. Without access to the other application, is it possible to see where the broadcast is getting? Thanks

Comment: I don't think so. Is there any documentation for this 3rd party app?

Comment: Im afraid not. Only been told by the devs:

"There are a few intents supported by the Company service that can be sent by other apps to interface with the service.

com.company.name.android.DO_STUFF

Send this intent to signal a button press."

Comment: Oh, if it's an IntentService, try "startService(intent)" instead of sendBroadcast

Comment: Hmm, with a bit more research, I believe you are right about it being IntentService. Still the implementation of the this sends the start broadcast but to no affect. I'll keep trying. Thanks for your help.